# ipod classic file With .VSp extension plays only on ipod, cannot convert

Tags: file-format, ipod

I have ipod classic 120GB. I installed a video file on it fron Sony camcorder(tape version) using Windows XP. The file extension indicates .VSP. Now this file only plays on ipod. I cannot convert it back to Pc in any format. Google search indicates there is no such file extension. My fear is when ipod battery runs out I will lose this file for ever.
I want yo convert this file to any video file format that I can play on Windows 10 or 11.
I have tried many video convertors from online search including Heart break, NCH video editor. No luck, all converters indicate file format not recoginized ot file corrupted.
Please help!! This 15 minute clip is very impotant to me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find, only
[VideoStudio Pro](https://www.videostudiopro.com/en/products/videostudio/pro/)
can convert VSP media (48,99 €, free for 30 days).

Comment: I downloaded VideoStudio Pro, it did not recognize the file format. I also Videostudio ver, 10(OLD), it does not recognize the file VSP file either. There is something strange about the file, a 15 minute clip is only 508kb, that tells me it is only somekind of header. The real file is probably hidden behind that only ipod can access.